# Bash loop for getting the first 12 characters in a filename, using the output to run touch -t command for each file

Tags: bash, loops, date

I've got a series of files in the following format:

YYYYMMDDHHmmXXXXXX.m4a in a directory

I'd like to write a script that will allow me to store each filename as a variable, let's call it MyFile, then store "YYYMMDDHHmm" (first 12 charachters of each file) as a variable, let's call it TimeStamp and use it to update the Date Created data for each file in the loop. The command should look something like:

`touch -t TimeStamp Myfile.m4a`

I'm new to writing scripts and have written the following which is returning an unexpected end at line 17

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

for f in /Users/username/music/M4Atest/*.m4a;

do filename=${f%%.*};

echo ${filename};

for ${filename};

do timestamp="${filename:0:12}";

echo ${timestamp};

done;
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: There is no line 17 in your script, and it's missing the second `done`.

Comment: I think you want `filename=$(f##*/}` first to remove all the directories in the `f` string. `${f%%.*}` removes everything from the first period on, but keeps all directories.

Comment: Ok, thanks @BenjaminW.

I've updated that and I'm now seeing the full filenames of the files in my directory and getting a `line 17 '${filename}': not a valid identifier`

Comment: @user2603941: The `for` statement expects a **variable name** after the keyword. Example: `for foo in ...; do ....; done`. A variable name consists of a combination of letters, digits and the underscore character, and the first character in a variable name must not be a digit. You write `for ${filename};`. The first character is a `$`. Hence this is not valid as a variable name.

Answer (score 2):

One loop is sufficient and use `${f##*/}` to remove the longest prefix pattern `*/` to get the filename.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s nullglob  # expands a glob pattern to a null string if the pattern doesn't match
for f in /Users/username/music/M4Atest/*.m4a; do
  filename=${f##*/}
  touch -t "${filename:0:12}" "$f"
done
```

If you want a safer filename pattern, you could use `[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9][0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9]?*.m4a` instead of `*.m4a`. This would make sure your filename contains at least the timestamp plus one character (`?`) plus any amount of characters (`*`) followed by the suffix `.m4a`.

```
# explanation:
# [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][01][0-9][0-3][0-9][0-2][0-9][0-5][0-9]?*.m4a
#    Y    Y    Y    Y   M    M    D    D    H    H    m    m
```

Comment: spot on. That has resolved it. Thank you very much. I'll try and break it all apart to understand what exactly it's doing but if it's not too much bother I would appreciate a short explanation if possible

Comment: What should I explain? 90% of the script is yours! The `shopt -s nullglob` enables Bash's `nullglob` feature and expands a non-matching glob pattern to a null string. If there are no `*.mp4` files in the directory, then the pattern expands to nothing and does not enter the loop. Without `nullglob` it would look for a file `/Users/username/music/M4Atest/*.m4a` (which doesn't exist).